# does using requires opening a sqlconnection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
//do i need to do this?
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        ....
    } //connection disposed
```

or will simply having a using close both opens and closes my connectoin?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {// connection opened
        ....
    } //connection disposed
```

Comment: you need to open a connection. The dispose will close it, though I like to be explicit. Of course, if you tried it you would quickly find out yourself...

Comment: Using manage connection by itself. Try above code and see what happens.

Comment: Try it yourself and let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to open it if you want to use it.

The [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0.aspx) simply creates a new object and populates some properties based on the connection string (or defaults if the connection string doesn't specify them). The [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) itself doesn't do anything extra on the object, it just starts a new block while creating the connection for the duration of that block.

I would also [close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx) (after committing any outstanding transactions explicitly since I think close does a rollback on these).

And I would also [dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx) of it, so as to not have to wait around for the garbage collector to finalise it (certain resources are held until disposal).